# Facebook information not populating Parse database

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-3.0

when users log-in through facebook in my app, I query for their picture and their name and use that info to populate Core Data and my Parse.com backend. However, it's not working. Here's the code that does everything:

```
#pragma mark - ()

- (IBAction)authButtonAction:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // If the person is authenticated, log out when the button is clicked.
    // If the person is not authenticated, log in when the button is clicked.
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [appDelegate closeSession];
    } else {
        // The person has initiated a login, so call the openSession method
        // and show the login UX if necessary.
        [appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
        self.authButton.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)toQuadAction:(id)sender {

    // Query to fetch the users name and picture
    NSString *query = @"SELECT name, username FROM user WHERE uid=me() ";

    // Set up the query parameter
    NSDictionary *queryParam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];
    // Make the API request that uses FQL
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql" parameters:queryParam HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"My name: %@", result[@"data"][0][@"name"]);
                              NSLog(@"My username: %@", result[@"data"][0][@"username"]);

                              //SAVE TO CORE DATA
                              AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                              NSEntityDescription *user = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
                              NSFetchRequest *getName = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
                              [getName setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
                              [getName setEntity:user];
                              NSError *error;
                              NSMutableArray *currentUser = [[appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:getName error:&error] mutableCopy];

                              //SAVE THE NAME TO CORE DATA
                              [currentUser[0] setName:result[@"data"][0][@"name"]];

                              //SAVE NAME AND PICTURE TO PARSE
                              PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Student"];
                              [query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:[currentUser[0] valueForKey:@"email"]];
                              [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *users, NSError *error) {
                                  if (!users){
                                      NSLog(@"The first object request failed");
                                  } else{
                                      NSLog(@"grabbed the object");
                                      //SET THE NAME IN PARSE
                                      [users setObject:result[@"data"][0][@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
                                      //SET THE IMAGE IN PARSE
                                      NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=235&height=385", result[@"data"][0][@"username"]];
                                      NSURL *picURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
                                      NSData *picData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:picURL];
                                      PFFile *picture = [PFFile fileWithData:picData ];
                                      [users setObject:picture forKey:@"picture"];
                                      [users saveInBackground];
                                  }
                              }];
                          }
                          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"facebookToQuad" sender:sender];
                      }];
    }
```

So, there's an auth button. The user clicks that and logs in with Facebook. Then another button appears allowing them to enter app. When they click that, we query their facebook profile for picture and name and add it core data, then to parse. However, right now, neither of those storage systems are being populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use more whitespace, and declare more instance variables.  Open your code out so you can find your problem easier.

For instance, pull out the value for
`result[@"data"][0][@"name"]`
and assign it to a local variable of it's own.

Subclass your entity in CoreData, so it's easier to manage attribute assignment with setters and getters.

Then set breakpoints and examine each step of the code.